# Adding a character to end of Item in ListView dependent on user Input

Tags: android, xml, listview, adapter

In my App (multiplication game) I have an actvity that displays the user's answers to questions.
If the given answer is correct it is shown in green. If the answer is wrong it is shown in red and the correct answer is shown in green in the sub-item.

I want to be able to add an "x" symbol after the answer if it is wrong and a tick symbol if it is correct. (in the item)

Image of activity as it is currently:

[image]

Code from activity:

```
public class RandomTestResults extends Activity {

    // Set up variables
    TextView scoreText;
    String phrase;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.testresults);

        // List view to hold the test results
        ListView itemList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvRandomTestresults);

        // getting data from the previous activity via intents
        int[] results = getIntent().getIntArrayExtra("results");
        String[] questions = getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("Questions");
        int[] correctAnswer = getIntent().getIntArrayExtra("CorrectAnswer");
        int score = getIntent().getIntExtra("score", 0);

        // if else statements to determine what phrase to present to user
        if (score <= 4) {
            phrase = "Please try again! ";
        } else if (score <= 6) {
            phrase = "Good effort! ";
        } else if (score <= 9) {
            phrase = "Well done! ";
        } else if (score == 10) {
            phrase = "Perfect! ";
        }

        // Set text to tell user what they scored in test
        scoreText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvRandomTestresults);
        scoreText.setText(phrase + "You got " + score + " correct out of 10!");

        // ArrayList containing Hashmap
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // loop to give list view (10 items and sub items)
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {

            // set userAnswer equal to correct place in results array
            int userAnswer = results[i - 1];
            // Setting expected answer to correct place in correctAnswer array
            int expectedAnswer = correctAnswer[i - 1];
            // Set string to present to user
            String userString = questions[i - 1] + " " + userAnswer; // mybe
                                                                        // change
            // correct answer
            String expectedString = "" + expectedAnswer;
            // HashMap containing 2 strings
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            // add strings to HashMap
            map.put("user", userString);
            map.put("expected", expectedString);
            // add HashMap to list
            list.add(map);
        }

        // Instantiate custom array adapter
        MyArrayAdapter adapter = new MyArrayAdapter(
                this.getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_row, list,
                questions, results);

        // Set custom adapter to your ListView.
        itemList.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    /**
     * Method that ensures user is returned
     * to main menu when they press back button
     */
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent t = new Intent(this, Menu.class);
        startActivity(t);
    }

}
```

Code from Adapter:

```
public class MyArrayAdapter extends
    ArrayAdapter<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> {
    Context mContext;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mQuestionArrayList;
    int mLayoutResourceId;
    String[] mQuestionsArray;
    int[] mUsersAnswers;

    /**
     * Constructor with arguments
     * @param context
     * @param layoutResourceId
     * @param questionsArrayList
     * @param questionsArray
     * @param usersAnswers
     */
    public MyArrayAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId,
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> questionsArrayList,
            String[] questionsArray, int[] usersAnswers) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId);
        mContext = context;
        this.mQuestionArrayList = questionsArrayList;
        this.mLayoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.mQuestionsArray = questionsArray;
        this.mUsersAnswers = usersAnswers;
    }

    /**
     * Method that returns the size 
     * of the ArrayList
     */
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mQuestionArrayList.size();
    }

    /**
     * 
     * Method that will get the view to display to user
     */
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View row, ViewGroup parent) {
        HashMap<String, String> question = mQuestionArrayList.get(position);
        //set layout inflater equal to context
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);

        // Initialize the row layout by inflating the xml file list_row.
        row = inflater.inflate(this.mLayoutResourceId, parent, false);

        // Initialize TextViews defined in the list_row layout.
        TextView questionTxtView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.question);
        TextView answerTxtView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.answer);
        TextView correctAnswerTxtView = (TextView) row
                .findViewById(R.id.correct);

        // Set text for each TextView
        questionTxtView.setText(mQuestionsArray[position]);
        answerTxtView.setText(String.valueOf(mUsersAnswers[position]));
        correctAnswerTxtView.setText(question.get("expected").toString());

        // Setting colour of the user answer dependent on if its correct
        if (mUsersAnswers[position] != Integer.parseInt(question
                .get("expected").toString())){
            answerTxtView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            correctAnswerTxtView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else{
            answerTxtView.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
            correctAnswerTxtView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        return row; 
    }
}
```

Two Corresponding XML's:

TestResults:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


        <TextView 
          android:id="@+id/tvRandomTestresults"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </TextView>

        <ListView 
           android:id="@+id/lvRandomTestresults"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        </ListView>


    </LinearLayout>
```

List_Row:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/list_row.xml"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/questionLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/question"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:paddingBottom="2dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/answer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:paddingBottom="2dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/correct"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#00FF00"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: add an ImageView after the input field for your custom list then display the check mark or X. Leave it blank until user inputs anything

Comment: Would i need an if statement to decide which image to display dependent on the users answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add ImageView:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/questionLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/question"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/answer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"/>

<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgResult"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:content_decription="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_incorrect" 
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"/>

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/correct"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#00FF00"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="2dp"
    android:paddingBottom="2dp"/>
```

getView() in adapter:

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View row, ViewGroup parent) {
        HashMap<String, String> question = mQuestionArrayList.get(position);
        //set layout inflater equal to context
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);

        // Initialize the row layout by inflating the xml file list_row.
        row = inflater.inflate(this.mLayoutResourceId, parent, false);

        // Initialize TextViews defined in the list_row layout.
        TextView questionTxtView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.question);
        TextView answerTxtView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.answer);
        ImageView imgResult = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imgResult);
        TextView correctAnswerTxtView = (TextView) row
                .findViewById(R.id.correct);

        // Set text for each TextView
        questionTxtView.setText(mQuestionsArray[position]);
        answerTxtView.setText(String.valueOf(mUsersAnswers[position]));
        correctAnswerTxtView.setText(question.get("expected").toString());

        // Setting colour of the user answer dependent on if its correct
        if (mUsersAnswers[position] != Integer.parseInt(question
                .get("expected").toString())){
            answerTxtView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            correctAnswerTxtView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            imgResult.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_incorrect);
        }
        else{
            answerTxtView.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
            correctAnswerTxtView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            imgResult.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_correct);
        }
        return row; 
    }
```

Comment: Would i need an if statment to decide which image to display dependent on the users answer?

Comment: Yes, in java code you need an if statment. If a answer is correct you put imgResult.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_correct); else imgResult.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_incorrect);

Comment: Thanks, Wer would I place this if statement within my code?

Comment: Also, Is there a way to make the images small enough to ensure that they with within each item of the list view?

Comment: Thanks, How can I ensure that the image is small enough to display within each list View?